# Is there a better layout than <table>?

Tags: html

When laying out a page, what are the alternatives to `<table>`? I've read in various places that tables weren't good for trying to layout pages. What *should* I use? `<div>`?

```
<table align="center" width="100%" height="250">
   <tr>
     <td align="left" width="25%"><?php require_once("page1.php"); ?></td>
     <td align="left" width="25%"><?php require_once("page2.php"); ?></td>
     <td align="left" width="25%"><?php require_once("page3.php"); ?></td>
     <td align="left" width="25%"><?php require_once("page4.php"); ?></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out a [css grid system](http://960.gs):

In a semantic, tableless layout, that code you posted would look something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div><?php require_once("page1.php");?></div>
   <div><?php require_once("page1.php");?></div>
   <div><?php require_once("page1.php");?></div>
   <div><?php require_once("page1.php");?></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { overflow-y:auto;}
.wrapper div { float:left;width:25%;}
```

Comment: Done!  Added overflow-y auto to .wrapper

Comment: Better yet make that `hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS - it's faster and more reliable.
There is a good article about this topic on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/practicalcss/).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better layout than `<table>`?

The question should be: Is there a worse layout than tables?

```
<div class="container">
  <div><?php require_once("page1.php"); ?></div>
  <div><?php require_once("page2.php"); ?></div>
  <div><?php require_once("page3.php"); ?></div>
  <div><?php require_once("page4.php"); ?></div>
</div>

.container { width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
.container > div { float: left; width: 25%; }
```

Check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rJkrG/).

Please note the `overflow: hidden;` trick on the container. This is because the inner divs have `float: left;`. When using `float` the container doesn't know the dimensions of the content. Because the divs are taken out of the normal flow of the document.

You should only use tables for tabular content NOT for layout purposes.

Rendering tables is slower than rendering divs. Tables are also less flexible. Also tables aren't semantically correct. (Well... divs aren't really sementic but hey it beats tables)

Another thing:

Please use CSS and keep you CSS separated from display logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
<ul>
   <li><?php require_once("page1.php");?></li>
   <li><?php require_once("page1.php");?></li>
   <li><?php require_once("page1.php");?></li>
   <li><?php require_once("page1.php");?></li>
</ul>
</div>
```